# How to switch E0 to E1 for extruder?

Tags: firmware, repetier

I have a K280 3D printer with a MKS V1.5 and Repetier firmware.

[image: Damaged transistor associated with E0 (3rd one on the right)]

I’ve damaged the transistor associated with E0 (3rd one on the right) and so that means I need to avoid that. I’ve decided to switch to E1 for the extruder but I have a feeling I need to go in the firmware or Repetier host and manipulate that.

I don’t know how and any help would be great.

The only info I can access for the firmware is the EEPROM and it seems that I can’t edit the pins. Also, do I need to edit the pin for the sensor or just where the extruder goes?

Comment: Can you switch the wiring between them?

Answer (score 2):

If you go through the [Repetier-Firmware configuration tool for version 1.0.2](https://www.repetier.com/firmware/v100/index.php) you can select the E1 stepper for the E0 extruder (or whatever stepper you want to use for it) in the tools tab sheet. I'm not familiar with Repetier, but if that does not work you would have to switch pin numbers.

If you already have a Configuration.h, you can use that one (by loading it into the configuration tool) and alter the E1 afterwards so that you do not have to enter all the other options by yourself.

**Edit:** After some investigation, you can find your configuration file [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1787070361537465/) as described [here](http://he3d-delta-printer-owners.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_Repetier_Software_for_the_first_time), so the only thing you would have to do is to load the file in the online tool and adjust the E1 stepper for E0 extruder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try editing the gcodes by searching and replacing E0 for E1, so this way the extruder E1 will be enabled.

Other way is setting the Slicer to use 2 extruders but everything for printing on E1 like: Perimeter, Infill, Solid, Support/raft/skirt, Support / raft interface.

The third one, Switch the transistor from E1 to E0 (your Q2 for Q1) or Q3 if you are not using the FAN output.